# jquery value of input field within class

Tags: jquery

I have several div's with the class **.agrRow**.
In each .agrRow there is an input field with the name **agrPrice**.

I want to get the value of that field for each instance of .agrRow.
I've tried something like:

```
    $(".agrRow").each(function(){           

            // get price for this field
            lp=parseFloat( $("input[type='text'][name='agrPrice']").val() );
    });
```

but that only ever gives me the value of agrPrice in the first instance of .agrRow class.

I'm sure I need to incorporate "this" but I'm not sure how.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: And what do you intend to do with all the values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find the input element in current teration context. you can use:

```
 $(".agrRow").each(function(){           
    // get price for this field
    lp=parseFloat($(this).find('[name=agrPrice]').val());
 });
```

To get them all in array:

```
  $(".agrRow [name=agrPrice]").map(function(){
    return parseFloat($(this).find('[name=agrPrice]').val());
  }).get()
```

Comment: **From OP:** _there is an input field with the name agrPrice._ not class `.agrPrice`

Comment: @AmitJoki: exactly. why make things complicated :). thnx for edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `this` context to get the input inside the iterating div.

```
$(".agrRow").each(function(){           
   // get price for this field
   lp=parseFloat($(this).find("input[type='text'][name='agrPrice']").val() );
});
```